# How Many Possible paths exist on Detroit: Become Human?

Tags: detroit-become-human

Let's take Grand Theft Auto V for example. There is just one important choice with three options. That makes 3 possible paths on a savegame.

Considering that Detroit: Become Human has more than 60 endings and 250 decisions, how many different combinations are possible on the story?

Comment: I don't know it this is a good question for here. But this will involve some calculations which is really difficult because there is not a set amount of branches per choice and some choices have more choices after it while another choice could end the chapter early

Comment: Define a path. If three completely unrelated parts of the story (i.e. decision tree) each have 2 outcomes, but since they don't affect each other, do you count that as 8 paths total (2*2*2) or 6 paths total (2+2+2)?

Comment: That would make it 8. Is about the decisions that the player can take, not the importance of it. Is like saving the fish or not on The Hostage: is not important for the story but the choice is there.

Comment: @Lemon: The player can make more choices than there are outcomes - some choices just don't meaningfully contribute to a different outcome. Other choices are cumulative (e.g. Connor's software instability, the relationships with other characters, ...). Player choices, meaningful individual decisions, meaningful cumulative decisions and story outcomes are all very different things, and there's little to no meaning to summing these up. As a simple example, me and my wife had very different stories but ended up with the same outcomes (except for 1 character who did(n't) make it)